# Haskell typing priority of operators over functions

Tags: function, haskell, types, operator-precedence, typing

I have to derive the type of this function:

```
func x = map -1 x
```

And I've already found a way, using a tip to change it to a lambda expression:

```
func = \x -> (map) - (1 x)
```

If I express it like that, its fine and I get the same type as the original, but I'm not sure why its grouped like this. Could someone explain it?

For example, why isn't it like this:

```
func = \x -> (map - 1) x
```

or something similar.

I know it's a useless function etc. but I can't change the function, I just have to derive its type.

If you write this function in a file, eg:
test.hs has `func x = map -1 x`
and use `:t func` in the interpreter, it will reply:

```
func :: (Num (t -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]),
         Num ((a -> b) -> [a] -> [b])) =>
         t -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Comment: Neither the code nor the text makes sense to me.

Comment: @Rhymoid I know that function doesn't make any sense and is simple useless, but i still have to type it. (check edit info)

So even if it's useless and doesnt have any sense, it still have type, and i'm wondering why to check type u have to group it like that, and not other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now believe you meant to ask why

```
func x = map -1 x
```

has the type `(Num (t -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]), Num ((a -> b) -> [a] -> [b])) => t -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, and how you can bracket the expression to make it have that type.

First, you have to recognise that the space is an operator in haskell, and has the highest precedence of all.

Let's use `#` instead of space, with highest precedence we can:

```
infixl 9 #
f # x = f x
```

We can replace and space without an operator with #:

```
func x = map - 1 # x
```

because the space between 1 and x was the only one without an operator (`-` is between `map` and `1`).

Since `#` has higher precedence than `-`, we get

```
func x = map - (1 # x)
```

or equivalently

```
func x = map - (1 x)
```

### Another example

```
func2 x = map (-1) x
```

```
> :t func2
func2 :: Num (a -> b) => [a] -> [b]
```

This translates as

```
func2' x = map # (-1) # x
```

but why isn't there a # between the `-` and the `1`? In this case, `-` in front of a numeric literal like `1` means `negate`:

```
> (-1)
-1
> (negate 1)
-1
> (subtract 1)
<interactive>:73:1:
    No instance for (Show (a0 -> a0))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (a0 -> a0))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

So this function is trying to map the negative of 1 over a list. For that to work, it would need negative 1 to be a function, which is why it needs a numeric instance for functions (the `Num (a->b) =>` at the start of the type).

Comment: Yep, that is what i was looking for ;) Simply
"because the space between 1 and x was the only one without an operator (- is between map and 1)" and that space (is it really an operator in Haskell? damn, what a strange language...) "has the highest precedence of all." Now i understand what and why, and i can find type of it (or try couple times before i find the good one ;)) myself. Thanks!

Comment: space really is an operator, as long as there's not another one, yes. It's function application. It beats writing all those brackets - `f x` is nicer than `f(x)` and `f x y` is more pleasant to type than the (uncurried) `f(x,y)`

Comment: For someone who wrote long time in C/C++ it is less obvious, since in C/C++ i know exactly which argument goes to which function - f(a,b,g(x,y,h(z))) - its pretty clear what goes where, and here it can get messy ;) Also - how does parser know when to use '-' as negate and whe as binary operator for subtraction? Or how it decides between those two?

Comment: The negate and the subtract versions have the same precedence, but in the formal syntax of the report, the rule for subtraction appears first, so where it makes sense as an operator (between two terms) it'll be the infix operator, but if there's nothing to the left of it, like in `- f x` or `(- x)` etc, it's negation.

Answer (score 2):

> but i'm not sure why its grouped like this. Could someone explain it? In example, why its not like that:
>
> ```
>    func = \x -> (map - 1) x
> ```

Precedence. The language definition [specifies that the precedence of (prefix) function application is higher than that of any infix operator](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-220003), so

```
map -1 x
```

is parsed as the application of the infix operator `(-)` to the two operands `map` and `1 x`, like `3 + 4 * 5` is parsed `3 + (4 * 5)` due to the higher precedence of `(*)` compared to that of `(+)`.

Comment: Thats what i was after, but i still dont get it fully:
Why:
    map -1 x
is parsed as (map) - (1 x). I mean second part - (1 x). There are no operator/function between two of them and '1' simply cannot be a function. So why they are in one "group" and it's not something like:
\x -> (map - 1) x which could work like if map would return function that would be applied to x, or even it could be interpretet as error.

Comment: There's white space between `1` and `x` and nothing else. Read a sequence of white space without a newline[1] as the function-application operator. `1` _can_ be a function, you can have for example a sensible `instance Num n => Num (a -> n)` where addition etc. of functions are defined pointwise (`f + g = \x -> f x + g x`). But regardless, the parsing comes before the type checking, and two expressions next to each other, separated only by white space is parsed as function application. [1]: The white space may actually contain a newline, it just mustn't decrease indentation.

Comment: That is something i was waiting for. Now for the last (i hope) question:
Am i thinking right to say, that it works like:
- we have func x = map -1 x  which could also look like: func x = map - 1 x. Parser comes to map, see's that i needs two arguments, gets first as '-', and then takes rest as the other, right? Or it works other way?
I just want to see how parser goes through this and takes which part when and for what. What come's first, what last etc.

Comment: @RippeR No, the parser doesn't know anything about `map`. It just sees an identifier, then it sees an operator. So it knows `map` is the left operand of `(-)`. Then it goes on, finds the integer literal `1`, so then it knows that if the expression is complete [no more tokens before the next (implicit) semicolon] or the next operator has lower precedence than `(-)`, then `1` is the right operand of `(-)`, otherwise, if the next operand has higher precedence, the right operator of `(-)` is an expression having `1` as a subexpression. Next operator is juxtaposition, which has highest precedence.

Comment: Thus the right operand of the `(-)` is ``1 `juxtapose` x`` (except that `juxtapose` is implicit in the source). After the parser is done, the type checker comes into play, and that knows about the types of the subexpressions.

Answer (score 1):

Although the interpreter has assigned a type to the expression, it's not a sensible one. Let's see what the function should be

```
func x = map -1 x
```

looks like we want to bracket that like this

```
func x = map (-1) x
```

in the hope that it subtracts one from each element of a list, but unfortunately, the `-` is considered to be negation when it's in front of a numeric literal, so we need to bracket it to change it into the subtraction function:

```
func x = map ((-) 1) x
```

Now this function subtracts each number in the list from 1:

```
 func [1,2,3]
=[(-) 1 1,  (-) 1 2,   (-) 1 3]
=[  1-1,      1-2,        1-3]
=[   0,       -1,         -2]
```

The type is

```
func :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
```

If you wanted to subtract one from each element of the list, rather than subtracting each element of the list from 1, you could use `func x = map (subtract 1) x`. As hammar points out, the `subtract` function exists exactly for the purpose of allowing this.

---

**Your alternative**

```
func = \x -> (map - 1) x
```

This can't work because `(-)` has type `Num a => a -> a -> a`, whereas `map` has type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. You can't subtract one from a function, because a function isn't a numeric value.

Comment: `((-) 1)` does not subtract `1`. It passes the `1` as the first argument, so it is the same as `(1 -)` or `\y -> 1 - y`. There is a `subtract` function which exists precisely for this purpose. Use that. E.g. `map (subtract 1) x`.

Comment: @hammar I've made it clearer that it doesn't work by using the phrase "in the hope that" instead of "so that".

Comment: I still think it's confusing to bring `((-) 1)` into the picture, when `subtract 1` is clearly what he meant (and what the code would mean if not for the whole negation thing).

Comment: @hammar I think it's a deliberately confusing exercise, not a bug in the OP's code. "I know that function doesn't make any sense and is simple useless, but i still have to type it."

Comment: @AndrewC as i stated i dont care if its good function or useless one that cant do anything. I just have to find types of it. I also have function like:
func2 x = map (-1) x, but it's other function than in topic. So you didn't really help me. :|

Comment: @RippeR So why ask? The interpreter already gave you the type. What do you need help with?

Comment: @AndrewC becouse it's not just for me or for fun to knew it, i HAVE TO know how excatly is it's type computed (and i can do it manually if i presume that this function changes to: func = \x -> (map) - (1 x), and i get good result, but i dont know why it groups it like that: (map) - (1 x) (especially part with (1 x)).
I'm studying in college and one of my excercises is to type a bunch of functions, that the one from topic is one of them.